# Get values from a TeX application file

Tags: output

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newwrite\stylesheetdetails%
\immediate\openout\stylesheetdetails\jobname.ssh%

\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\stylesheetdetails}%

\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{6truein}%

\immediate\write\stylesheetdetails{Trim size\space\the\paperwidth\space x\space\the\paperheight\space inches}%


\begin{document}

This is for test

\end{document}
```

I need to get the `Trim size` values and need to store in a separate file with extension of `.ssh`, I tried with the above, but the output came as:

```
Trim size 433.62pt x 650.43pt inches
```

But I need the output in `inches` or whatever I given (e.g., some time it may be in `mm`) not the `point values`, please suggest, how to get it...

Comment: Internally TeX does not save the units of lengths: if you want to recover them, you'll need to store in macros. Would that be a suitable approach for you?

Comment: @JosephWright Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to save the lengths in macros for writing out, but of course still set `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` to have effect on the PDF. That is best done using a short wrapper, for example

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\newwrite\stylesheetdetails
\immediate\openout\stylesheetdetails\jobname.ssh %

\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\stylesheetdetails}

\newcommand*\savedpaperheight{0pt}
\newcommand*\savedpaperwidth{0pt}

\NewDocumentCommand\setpapersize{mm}{%
  \setlength{\paperheight}{#1}%
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{#2}%
  \renewcommand*\savedpaperheight{#1}%
  \renewcommand*\savedpaperwidth{#2}%
}

\setpapersize{9truein}{6truein}

\immediate\write\stylesheetdetails{Trim size \savedpaperheight\space x \savedpaperwidth}


\begin{document}

This is for test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Much thanks, it's working beautifully, thanks a lot