# Need to store some values in a separate output file

Tags: output

My current code is:

```
\documentclass{book}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{6in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{27pc}
\setlength{\textheight}{39pc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{10}{12}%
   \abovedisplayskip 12\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@%
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip%
   \let\@listi\@listI}%
\normalsize%

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
\footnotesize%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{#1\ignorespaces\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces#2}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\hsize
  {\sc #1.}\ignorespaces\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces#2%
  \else
    \hbox to \hsize{\hss{\sc #1.}\ignorespaces\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces#2\hss}
  \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test
\end{document}
```

Like need to some more tags in the same format, like List `topsep` and `itemsep`, and `reference font size and its itemsep value`, etc.

And I want to restore the values into a separate output file, e.g.,

**Output file content**

```
Paper size = 6in, 9in

Text size = 27pc, 39pc

Normal text font size = 10/12

Figure caption size = 8/10
```

Is it possible to create within LaTeX compilation or else some other suggestions are welcome, please

Comment: Is it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666050/get-values-from-a-tex-application-file/666057#666057 helpful for you?

Comment: Writing an ASCII file is easy.  See `\openout`, `\write` and `\closeout` (the TeXbook).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Per your advise, I got success regarding `\openout, \write` and `\closeout` also with the help too from `MadyYuvi's` link, but not able to write the values of Trim size, Text size, captionsize, etc. Can you please advise on the same? Please

Comment: You could use more than one `\write` before `\closeout`, or figure out what to replace `\cr` with using LaTeX. (\\ ?).